# Is there a shorter way of saying "turned up in a timely fashion" or "turned up just in time"?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there a shorter way of saying "turned up in a timely fashion" or "turned up just in time"?

As in:

> The DJ turned up just in time to appease the crowd. If she didn't come
> in time, it would have degenerated into a full-blown riot.

I think there's a way of saying this, but I can't remember the right word or phrase.

Comment: Are you thinking of [**in the nick of time**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20nick%20of%20time)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The DJ turned up just in time to appease the crowd. If she didn't come in time, it would have degenerated into a full-blown riot.

There is a slight difference between *turned up in a timely fashion" and "turned up just in time"; the latter suggests a higher sense of urgency and is preferred; from the context of this passage, especially the noun phrase *full-blown riot*, we see such an urgency.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/just%20in%20time

For further brevity, we could replace the phrasal verb *turned up* with another verb, like *arrived* or *appeared*, etc.

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/turn%20up

We could also use *the situation* to replace the propoun *it*, which has no antecedent.

> The DJ turned up/arrived just in time to appease the crowd. If she didn't come in time, *the situation* would have degenerated into a full-blown riot.